# The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to run a Package in Visual Studio which includes a UWP and a Console. I get a "The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)" on the following lines:

```
    private async void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
        {
            await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
        }

    }
```

on the last closing bracket. Windows 10 and Visual Studio are up-to-date on my computer.

Here is the App manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity
    Name="6d600000-922a-4cd3-8f19-a6afc21809f9"
    Publisher="CN=11031121"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>WapProjTemplate2</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>11031121</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="WapProjTemplate2"
        Description="WapProjTemplate2"
        BackgroundColor="transparent"
        Square150x150Logo="Images\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Images\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Could you please provided us with some detailed code about packaging in manifest?

Comment: okay I just edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `windows.fullTrustProcess` Extensions in your **Package** manifest when you are using the [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041) class.

For example:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      ……

        <Extensions>
            <desktop:Extension
              xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
              Category="windows.fullTrustProcess"
              Executable="MyConsole/MyConsole.exe" />
        </Extensions>
        
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

Note, `MyConsole`(replace your **Console** project name) is the name of **Console** project. You need to run your console project first.